# Do we have to use GUIDs in LinqToSql application to uniquely identify objects

Tags: linq-to-sql, guid, identity

I have inherited a LinqToSql application which is making use of GUID keys for objects. 
I'd rather use conventional identity fields - much easier for people to use, understand and communicate. However there is some business logic that requires the application to identify unique objects before they're persisted to the DB which is why GUIDs where used in the first place.

Another issue we're having is with fragmented indexes - AFAIK we can't create sequential GUIDs in .Net code.

As this is my first exercise in LinqToSql I'd like to know how others have addressed this issue.

BTW there is no need for the data between multiple servers to be combined - the main (only) reason that I've used GUID keys in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to use Guids, you can use any key type you'd like.

If you are stuck with Guids consider having the database generate them sequentially for you by making the default binding for the pk field `newsequentialid()`. This will eliminate fragmentation in your clustered index at least. You need to make a few modifications to the .dbml if you do this. On the key field in the .dbml `Auto Generated Value = true` and `Auto-Sync = OnInsert`

As far as generating the value before you insert to the database I don't see how using an identity field helps you. You will still have to insert to the database to reliably get the correct value. (Identity columns will have the same Autogenerated/Autosync settings as above)

Ints or Guids, you should be able to wrap the insert in a transaction, insert the record, grab the new key value, run your business logic and if it fails roll back the newly inserted record.

Comment: Using an Identity field breaks our need to generate a unique key value - that's our key problem. But using a GUID seems such a big trade off just to get unique keys inside our app.

Comment: My point was it doesn't matter whether you use guids or ints, you can have the database generate proper sequential values for either and both will work just fine with linq to sql.  Are you planning on generating the key int in code or in the database? I assumed from your question you were going to let the DB do it. Then you mention you want the value before you put it in the database which isn't easily doable, thus the transaction around you object insert and business logic.

Comment: Oh, and I agree you probably don't need guids. It shouldn't be too hard for you to refactor the existing code to use ints instead.